# Should answer-owners be highlighted like question-owners?

Tags: feature-request, answers, design, users, information-display

On question pages on SE, the owner of a question is easy to identify: his "`post-signature`" has additional css-markup: `owner`.

If the owner comments on the page, his/her username is highlighted, blue on SO.

I'm wondering whether it would be an enhancement if comments of the answerer are highlighted in the comments section of that answer (in another color). This could be useful since:

- An answerer is a **stakeholder** in the process as well and thus has a "more important" status than "*just a random user*" (no insult intended). He/she is after all, the owner of the answer.
- There is a better **distinction** between people who *might* understand the answer and the person who produced the answer and thus fully understands it;
- People can identify a **third party** more easily: it is obvious the answerer will of course defend his/her answer whereas a third party's positive comment gives an answer more "*authority*".

This is of course a very unimportant enhancement proposal. But as some HCI researchers argue: "Every second counts, and with millions of users, even a tiny increase in user's performance results in saving years for the total user community."

If the request is not accepted, why?

Comment: Userscript over [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/5075/answerer-name-comment-highlighter)